# JCL/JVCL for Delphi 11: What happened to JwaLmShare.pas file

Tags: delphi, jedi

I am converting a Delphi 7 application to Delphi 11. The source code refers to some JCL classes (TShareInfo502) used for creating shared folders.
The class TShareInfo502 is define3d in the file JwaLmShare for Delphi 7.
I have installed the latest version of JCL/JVCL for Delphi 11 and that unit is not included.
I have also searched all the source for TShareInfo and nothing is found.

Does anyone know if they simply removed that code and made it obsolete in the latest JCL or am I supposed to use a different class in Delphi 11?

TIA

Comment: You could try using [this one](https://github.com/magicmonty/delphi-code-coverage/blob/master/3rdParty/JWAPI/jwapi2.2a/Win32API/JwaLmShare.pas)